# How to change a specific word

Tags: magento-1.8, localisation

In the product listings of our site, the dropdown text for customers has a typo - it reads, "Select options below for price and avilability."  So the word "avilability" needs to be edited to "availability."  Not sure how to do that.

Comment: can you share the screenshot, it may be coming from one of phtml file depending on your theme and template you are using.

Answer (score 1):

the most simple way is to search in the whole code where the specific word was wrongly typed.

The alternate solution is to use Magento's translate system, but I dont recommend that because it is likely you need to know the module context which is harder to find then the source of the typo.